# MongoDB (Java) if statement equals value

Tags: java, mongodb, if-statement, equals

So I'm working on a piece of code with a `if` statement and in the `if` statement i want to check if a value of my MongoDB equals `"test"`

I currently have this it isn't much but i really don't know how to do this

```
  if (DBManager.getInstance().getTestCollection()) {
```

Example of my MongoDB

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "56fd47ea18de75129095d841"
},
"foo": "test"
}
```

Comment: what does getTestCollection() return?

Comment: `public MongoCollection<Document> getTestCollection() {
  return database.getCollection("test_collection");
 }`

Comment: What do you mean by *a value of my MongoDB* though? Show an example of your data and the field/item you want to find. (edit your question with the relevant information)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the collection, you need to Aquire cursor on it and loop through it. see below.

```
    DBCollection testCollection = DBManager.getInstance().getTestCollection()
    DBCursor cursor = testCollection.find();

        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
            if ("test".equals(obj.get("foo")) {
               System.out.println("Found");
            }
        }
```

Comment: `DBCollection testCollection = DBManager.getInstance().getTestCollection()`

Want's me to cast `com.mongodb.DBCollection;`

Comment: did you try casting?

Comment: Yes, `DBCollection testCollection = (DBCollection) DBManager.getInstance().getTestCollection();`

But now i get this error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBCollection`

Comment: Which version of mongo driver you are using? I am using version3 and it works without any issues.